# How to download libxml2.so for android 9 without downloading android aosp

Tags: android, android-source

I want to download libxml2.so, libpcap.so and libz.so for android 9.
I know that we can download aosp and then take it from there. But I dont have the resources to download it now.

So is there a way to download these .so libraries directly from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `zip` file containing all binaries from [ci.android.com](https://ci.android.com/). If you want to have the x86 binaries you could unzip [aosp_x86-target_files-XXXXXXX.zip](https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/5844306/aosp_x86-eng/latest/aosp_x86-target_files-5844306.zip) and get it from `SYSTEM/lib/libxml2.so`.